# $npm install -g npm@latest Wont work properly

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to upgrade npm version, so updated node to v10.1.0 then did

> npm install -g npm@latest

but still remain version of v5.6.0 after I checked with

> npm -v
>
> 5.6.0

Can you help me to upgrade this to 6.1.0 or any latest version of npm.

Thank you in advance to all who help me on this question...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkCLi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux/Unix or Windows?

It works to me.

If Linux based you need to `sudo npm install -g npm@latest` (sudo)

Comment: Thanks for your help, my spec is
Mac os High SIerra

Comment: Thanks for your help, my spec is
Mac os High SIerra

sudo npm install -g npm@latest

` repoet $sudo npm install -g npm@latest
Password:
/Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
/Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@6.1.0
updated 1 package in 120.289s
repoet $npm --v
5.6.0 `

Comment: ` repoet 
$sudo npm install -g npm@latest 

Password: 

/Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/bin/npx -> 

/Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js 

/Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/bin/npm -> 

/Users/GenkiA/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js + npm@6.1.0 

updated 1 package in 120.289s repoet 

$npm --v 5.6.0 `
</code>

Comment: No, it didn't change my npm version...  I tried but the version of npm still remains 5.6.0 ... even though the 6.1.0 is already installed..

Comment: that's weird, is it because u did not install node as system level but install as user level? Sorry I am not export of linux